# Receiving NONE_PROVIDED in username parameter in the loadUserByUsername() function in Spring Boot 3.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am making an authentication feature for my Spring Boot API using **Spring Security** and **OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer**. I am storing the user details in a MySQL database. For an authentication request, I want to check if the user exists in the database or not.

I kept breakpoints at the overridden *loadUserByUsername()* function and I am getting userName parameter as ***NONE_PROVIDED***. The username that I am trying to fetch exists in the database table. I even tried to test the *findByUserName()* repository method by passing the username that I want to authenticate and it returned me the user result but I could not understand that why that particular username is not being passed in the UserDetails method.

Attaching my code snippets below.

This is my User class.

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "newUser")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(int userId, String userName, String password) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User Repository Class

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.
                    sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(
                        OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                return userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("userDetailsService")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        var authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    //Other beans for JWT encoding and decoding

}
```

The Controller class

```
@RestController
public class JwtAuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    private final JwtTokenService tokenService;
    
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtAuthenticationController(JwtTokenService tokenService, 
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtTokenResponse> generateToken(
            @RequestBody JwtTokenRequest jwtTokenRequest) {
        
        var authenticationToken = 
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        jwtTokenRequest.username(), 
                        jwtTokenRequest.password());
        
        var authentication = 
                authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        
        var token = tokenService.generateToken(authentication);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtTokenResponse(token));
    }
}
```

The pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>react.api.helloworldv3</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworldv3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworldv3</name>
    <description>Hello World</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You are implementing the same worst practices as the author of [this other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77176116/619830). Switch to [formLogin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html) and sessions or see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176424/619830) for proper OAuth2 implementation.